# Javascript & jQuery push array to object based on custom attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

**Problem**

There are a couple of HTML tags with classes as follows

```
<span class=​"keyword" column-name=​"Product Group">​Outdoors</span>​
<span class=​"keyword" column-name=​"Material Code">​10001003​</span>​
<span class=​"keyword" column-name=​"Material Code">​10001000​</span>​
```

All the `span` needs to be iterated through and a new object would be created with the column-name attribute as its property and the relevant text passed into an array.

**Code So Far**

I am using the below code but the array passed consists of all the text from the span

```
var searchCriteria = {};
var keyword = [];
$('.keyword').each(function(index, elem) {
    col = $(elem).attr('column-name');
    keyword.push($(elem).text());
    searchCriteria[col] = (keyword);
});
console.log(searchCriteria);
```

The above code prepares the object as

```
{
    Material Code: ['Outdoors', '10001003', '10001000']
    Product Group: ['Outdoors', '10001003', '10001000']
}
```

**Result Expected**

The result of the object which I am expecting is

```
{
    Material Code: ['10001003', '10001000']
    Product Group: ['Outdoors']
}
```

**JS Fiddle**

Here is a JSFiddle of the same - http://jsfiddle.net/illuminatus/0g0uau4v/2/

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: I really suggest you refactor your HTML and make it more semantic, it's really badly written.

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos; Any feedback of what needs to be changed with the HTML? And what are the repercussion that you can see with the existing markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `searchCriteria[col] = (keyword);`, it does not copy the keyword array. It just stores pointer to that array. So, if you update keyword after assigning it to some variable, it'll also get updated as both of them points to the same array. If you want to copy array you may use `.slice()` on array. But here it is not needed.

Use the following code instead

```
var searchCriteria = {};
$('.keyword').each(function(index, elem) {
    col = $(elem).attr('column-name');
    if ( !Array.isArray(searchCriteria[col]) )
        searchCriteria[col] = [];
    searchCriteria[col].push($(elem).text());
});
console.log(searchCriteria);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0g0uau4v/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the same array as the value for each column. Instead, create a new array each time you encounter a new column, or simply append the value to the existing array if the `column-name` already exists:

```js
$(function() {
    var searchCriteria = {};
    $('.keyword').each(function(index, elem) {
        var col = $(elem).attr('column-name');
        var keyword = searchCriteria[col] ? searchCriteria[col] : [];
        keyword.push($(elem).text());
        searchCriteria[col] = (keyword);
    });
    $("#result").text("Result: " + JSON.stringify(searchCriteria));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="keyword" column-name="Product Group">Outdoors</span>
<span class="keyword" column-name="Material Code">10001003</span>
<span class="keyword" column-name="Material Code">10001000</span>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: This worked great. I had a hunch that something is wrong with the array declaration, but could not figure out what. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can instead do this

```
var searchCriteria = {};
$('.keyword').each(function(){
   var key = $(this).attr("column-name");
   var value = $('[column-name='+key+']').map(function(){return $(this).text()}).get();
   if(!searchCriteria.hasOwnProperty(key)) searchCriteria[key] = value;
});
```

Comment: Clever way to use `map`...but JS objects don't have a `push` method. That last line should simply be `searchCriteria[key] = value;`.

Comment: @nbrooks thanks.. push only exists in arrays.. forgot that. :)

Answer (score 0):

That was becoz, you were using same updated array for all.

```
var searchCriteria = {};
var keyword = [];
$('.keyword').each(function(index, elem) {
    col = $(elem).attr('column-name');
    if( !searchCriteria[col])
         searchCriteria[col] = [];
    searchCriteria[col].push($(elem).text());
});
console.log(searchCriteria);
```

Here in this code im searching for, if property doesn't exist . Then make that index as array. And futher you push elements.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayurRahul/shtmok9j/)